# Swagger 3 nested array define structure

Tags: swagger

I am looking to create a response that looks like the following:

```
permissions:
{
    "customers":['add_update','delete'],
    "employees":['add_update','delete']
    "suppliers":['add_update','delete','search]
}
```

OR (customers,employees..dynamic)

```
permissions:
{
    "customers":['add_update','delete']
}
```

Is this possible to do using ref's in swagger?

I have tried this but cannot figure out how to get the "customers","employees","suppliers" as keys.

```
EmployeePermissions:
  type: object
  properties:
    module:
     type: string
     example: 'customers'
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about your use-case (my reading ability) but have you looked into `allOf` ?

Comment: Are `"add_update"`, `"delete"` and `"search"` enum values or random values?

Comment: add_update,delete,search are random values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a map in swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644595/how-to-define-a-map-in-swagger)

Answer (score 0):

Each property (`properties`, `employees` and `suppliers`) needs to have its own entry under `properties`.

```yaml
EmployeePermissions:
  type: object
  properties:
    customers:     # <----- property name
      type: array  # <----- property type
      items:
        type: string
    employees:     # <----- property name
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
    suppliers:     # <----- property name
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
```

More info about defining objects in OpenAPI: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#object

Comment: But I need it to be dynamic and optional. (customers,employees..etc).

Comment: @ChrisMuench Like a map/dictionary, where `customers`, `employees`, etc. are random keys? Something like `<string, array[string]>`?

Comment: @ChrisMuench: Or are the `customers`, `employees` etc. fixed property names but all properties are optional?

Comment: They are random keys that is dynamic but each key has an array of strings